# How to delete a file that has a name of type wchar_t in C++ in a portable way?

Tags: c++

I need to delete a file whose name is defined using wchar_t*. What's the best way to do this?

remove takes a const char* as argument.

Apparently, there is _wremove, but only for windows.

What is considered best practice (portable) to handle this? I could convert the file name to char*, but that misses the point. The file name may have an accent or some other unicode character.

Before somebody says "this is a terrible idea! you should not use wchar_t* for file names!", I did not design the thing. I have been asked to do it that way for whatever reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like filesystem operations have been [added into the standard library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) since C++17 if you can use it. Otherwise, you can use [Boost.Filesystem](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm). Don't know about best practice, but to me this sounds like the way to go.